# Cannot find -lGL but I've installed the Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.04, opengl

I'm trying to compile a simple "Hello World" program in Qt Creator, but I always get this message:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/paul/Apps/Qt/5.3/gcc_64 \
  -Wl,-rpath,/home/paul/Apps/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib -o hello_world main.o qrc_qml.o \
  -L/home/paul/Apps/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Quick -lQt5Qml -lQt5Widgets \
  -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

As the title states, I've installed the Nvidia driver and when I run `ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so`, I get this:

```
paul@kreker-desktop:~$ ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so
        libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.1
        libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.1
        libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so
        libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so
```

Is there something I have to install that I have missed? What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Can you post your actual compile command line so we can see the link parameters?

Comment: Of course... I've added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-331/libGL.so /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

Or you can install GLX development files:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: Would that mean I'm linking against the mesa driver or am I still using the nvidia driver for compiling?

Comment: @PaulKreker I don't know that, but I've found a way to link against Nvidia's `libGL`. See answer.

Comment: I've just installed the libgl1-mesa-dev since the compiler didn't find header files in /usr/include/GL after I created the symlink. But thank you for your reply. :)

Comment: To me this is only a temporary answer. What happens when nvidia driver/dev libs version is updated?